# Get all public fields with values in object of Scala class

Tags: scala, reflection

How to get all public fields (including inherited) and their values from 
the object of Scala class?

This:

```
class A(val a: String)

class B(val b: String) extends A("a")

val b = new B("b")

b.getClass.getFields
```

returns empty list.

Comment: A combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708485/scala-class-getfields and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658060/how-to-access-a-fields-value-via-reflection-scala-2-8 should be a good place for you to start. AKA, reflection.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? There seems to be an endless stream of people wanting to dynamically unpick data structures, but the reason for wanting to do this is never clear. I fear it is because they are trying to re-create features from another language rather than use the features in Scala.

Comment: I want to build http request with url params taken from case classes in Scala. I don't want to add some 'parse' method to each such class. My intention is to implement retrieving of values in one place, not in each class.

Comment: This sounds like a use case for a _compile time reflection_ rather than _runtime reflection_. So either Shapeless or Scala macros.